# yet another: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java

I have a common problem but the common solutions seems don't work for me.

I have a file called test.java in my current directory with others class files in the myclasses directory. Namely if i type

```
ls:
myclasses  test.java
```

I type:

```
  javac test.java
```

and all compile fine.

When i try to execute test.class and then type:

```
  java test
```

i get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test (wrong name: myclasses/test)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: test.  Program will exit.
```

I guess that this means that java can't locate the test.class file. But why? the file is in the current directory and all classes are in the myclasses directory. I have tried different combinations of flags (-cp , -d -sourcepath) and i have moved the test.class around the directories.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: The class name is case sensitive. Check it. Execute the `ls` command again and see the name of `.class` file. Also make sure that the class is a public one.

Comment: what is the connection to ant?

Comment: as a sidenode, java classes should be uppercase-camelcase by convention.

Comment: How have you defined your classpath? Have you tried java -cp ./myclasses test? (I'm assuming the case of the class matches the filename "test.java") Can you post your test.java code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that `test.java` contains `public static void main` method.

Also, if your class is inside `myclasses`, you should `java myclasses.test`, i believe

Comment: yes, test.java has public static void main and no, it is not inside myclasses.

Comment: **No**, it's `java myclasses.test` (dot instead of slash). The `java` executable accepts class names, not file names.

Comment: thanx, no better, it is perfect! but why javac put my class test inside myclasses directory?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, make sure there is no package name (`myclasses`) declared in your .java file.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify classpath for searching the Class.

```
java -cp . test
```